# Suggestion for R function

Tags: r

I am just starting off in R and trying to write a function that can give me a summary for NA's by the columns in the data. I have a couple of questions:

1. If I pass a list, how can the function pick its name? For example, if I pass 'listA', the function should return listA with the number of NA's underneath. Currently, it returns 'x' and the number of NA's under. For example:

   ```
    E <- c(NA,1,2,3); na_cols_summary(E)
   ```

   yields

   ```
    $x
    [1] NA
   ```
2. Can someone suggest, how can I use a function from the 'apply' family to make the function more elegant.
3. Do we have a package/ function with a similar functionality?

   ```
   ###Sample Data
   A <- c(1:10)
   B <- c(11:20)
   C <- c(21:30)
   D <- c(31:40)
   df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
   df <-
     as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc)
       cc[sample(
         c(TRUE, NA),
         prob = c(0.85, 0.15),
         size = length(cc),
         replace = TRUE
       )]))



   na_cols_summary <- function(x) {
      x <- as.data.frame(x)
      y <- colSums(is.na(x))
      y <- y[y != 0]
      nalis <- list()
      i <- 1
      for (z in names(y)) {
           nalis[i] <- list(x[is.na(x[, z]), ])
           i <- i + 1
       }
      names(nalis) <- names(y)
      return(nalis)
      }
   df_na <- na_cols_summary(df)

   df_na
   $A
      A  B  C  D
   3  NA NA 23 33
   4  NA 14 24 34
   10 NA 20 30 40

   $B
      A  B  C  D
   3 NA NA 23 33
   8  8 NA 28 38
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `lapply`.

This mimics your function.

```
lapply(df2 <- df1[colSums(is.na(df1)) > 0], function(x) df2[is.na(x), ])
# $A
#    A  B  C
# 1 NA 11 NA
# 2 NA 12 22
# 
# $B
#   A  B  C
# 3 3 NA NA
# 6 6 NA 26
# 7 7 NA 27
# 
# $C
#    A  B  C
# 1 NA 11 NA
# 3  3 NA NA
# 4  4 14 NA
# 8  8 18 NA
```

To get not just the missing-columns into the output just do `lapply(df1, function(x) df1[is.na(x), ])`.

To get your object's name you could use `deparse(substitute(.))`

```
f <- function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
f(E)
# [1] "E"
```

To combine this into a function, you could do:

```
na_cols_summary2 <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(x) | is.vector(x))
  if (!any(is.na(x))) {
    return(message("No missings found.\n"))
  }
  if (is.data.frame(x)) {
    res <- lapply(x, function(i) x[is.na(i), ])
    res <- res[lapply(res, nrow) > 0]
  } else {
    res <- setNames(as.data.frame(x), deparse(substitute(x)))
  } 
  return(res)
}
```

#### Usage

```
na_cols_summary2(df1)
# $A
#    A  B  C  D
# 1 NA 11 NA 31
# 2 NA 12 22 32
# 
# $B
#   A  B  C  D
# 3 3 NA NA 33
# 6 6 NA 26 36
# 7 7 NA 27 37
# 
# $C
#    A  B  C  D
# 1 NA 11 NA 31
# 3  3 NA NA 33
# 4  4 14 NA 34
# 8  8 18 NA 38

na_cols_summary2(E)
#    E
# 1 NA
# 2  1
# 3  2
# 4  3

na_cols_summary2(E2)
# No missings found.

na_cols_summary2(matrix(0, 4))
# Error in na_cols_summary2(matrix(0, 4)) : 
#  is.data.frame(x) | is.vector(x) is not TRUE
```

#### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(NA, NA, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), 
    B = c(11L, 12L, NA, 14L, 15L, NA, NA, 18L, 19L, 20L), C = c(NA, 
    22L, NA, NA, 25L, 26L, 27L, NA, 29L, 30L), D = c(31, 32, 
    33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

E <- c(NA, 1, 2, 3)
E2 <- 1:4
```